# IndexOf a string

Tags: javascript, loops

I need a function that works like `IndexOf`

```
var str = "test*index*ofAnyChar";
  console.log(str.indexOf("*", 5)); // output will be 10

var str = "test*index*ofAnyChar";
  console.log(str.indexOf("*", 0)); // output will be 4
```

to get a string, indexvalue, startfrom and return the value other way than the built in function `return str.indexOf(indexValue,startFrom)`

```
function Findindex(str, indexValue, startFrom){

      }
```

I want the output of `('str*index*of123123E32132s', '*', 0)`
to be `3`

and

I want the output of `('str*index*of123123E32132s', '*', 4)`
to be `9`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: so, `return str.indexOf(indexValue, startFrom)` ? you serious?

Comment: @JaromandaX I need to return value using loop

Comment: what loop - a function can return a single value only, so not sure what a loop has to do with it - perhaps if you showed some code that looks like an attempt to solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use a loop to iterate through a string. Use a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop.

```
function Findindex(str, indexValue, startFrom){
  let i = 0;
  for(const char of str){
    if(!(i>=startFrom)){
      i++;
      continue;
    }
    if(char==indexValue) return i;
    i++;
  }
}
```

#### Without loop

[String.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Its syntax:

> str.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])

The description of the second parameter:

> An integer representing the index at which to start the search; the default value is 0. For fromIndex values lower than 0 or greater than str.length, the search starts at index 0 and str.length respectively.

As you can see, indexOf takes a second parameter, allowing you to tell it where to search from.

You can use it as such

```
function Findindex(str, indexValue, startFrom){
   return str.indexOf(indexValue,startFrom);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to solve it. In this method, you only iterate from the index you need and stop when you find a match.

Note: I also renamed the function so that the naming convention is followed.

```js
function findIndex(str, indexValue, startFrom=0){
  for (let i = startFrom; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === indexValue) return i
  }
}

console.log(findIndex('str*index*of123123E32132s', '*', 0))
console.log(findIndex('str*index*of123123E32132s', '*', 4))
```

You can optionally add a `return -1` statement after the for loop if you want to handle cases where it finds no match.